# Topology of an interval

Tags: general-topology

$ [ \; - \; 1 \; , \; 1 \; ] $ is clopen in its own topology, so all of it's points must be interior and it must contain all of its limit points; however I do not see any neighborhood around the endpoints $- \; 1 $ or $1$.

Comment: A neighborhood of $-1$ is of the form $[-1,-1+\varepsilon)$ and of $1$ the form $(1-\varepsilon,1]$, for $0<\varepsilon<1$.

Comment: But that's the thing - in the subspace topology on $[-1,1]$, an interval of the form $[-1,-1+\varepsilon)$ isn't a "half-open" set, it is an open set (and a closed set). Remember that we are restricting ourselves only to the numbers in that interval.

Comment: No, of course not. Take the set $\{0\}$, which is finite and clearly closed, but is $0$ an interior point of $[-1,1]$ so the set cannot be open.

Comment: There is no neighborhood which is a subset of $\{0\}$, yes.

Comment: Well for example the interval $(0,1/2)$ would not be closed, as it does not contain its limit points $0$ and $1/2$, and the interval $[0,1/2]$ would not be open, as $0$ and $1/2$ are not interior points of $[0,1/2]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After defining the concept of a *metric space* Rudin explains in Example 2.16 that

"It is important to observe that every subset $Y$ of a metric space $X$ is a metric space in its own right, with the same distance funtion."

For $p  \in Y  \subset X$ you have

1. The open ball $N_r(p;X) = \{ q \in X \mid d(p,q) < r \}$ **in $X$**.
2. The open ball $N_r(p;Y) = \{ q \in Y \mid d(p,q) < r \}$ **in $Y$**.

Obviously $N_r(p;Y) = N_r(p;X) \cap Y$, but in general $N_r(p;Y) \subsetneqq N_r(p;X)$. For $Y = [-1,1] \subset \mathbb R$ the open balls around a point $p$ in $[-1,1]$ are intervals of the form

1. $(p-r,p+r)$ if $-1 \le p-r$ and  $p + r \le 1$.
2. $[-1,p+r)$ if $-1 > p-r$ and  $p + r \le 1$.
3. $(p-r,1]$ if  $-1 \le p-r$ and  $p + r > 1$.
4. $[-1,1]$ if$-1 > p-r$ and  $p + r > 1$.

Thus the collection of open balls of $[-1,1]$ consists of all open intervals $(a,b)  \subset [-1,1]$, all half-open intervals $[-1,b) \subset [-1,1]$ and $(a,1] \subset [-1,1]$, and $[-1,1]$.

See also Remark 2.29 and Theorem 2.30 in Rudin.